# exceptions handling error scenario

Tags: java, spring, exception, httpexception

I have the following scenario:

```
  Class C{
  mainCall(){
try{
     //do something;
 }catch(MyException e)
     //doSomethingElse;
  }
}

Class A{
methodOne() throws myException{
 b.callMethodTwo();
}
}

class B{
callMethodTwo() throws myException{
  try {
            value = callService()//call some service
        } catch(HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e){
            throw new MyException(e);
        }
 return value;
   }
}
```

if some exceptions occured in callMethodTwo() (**not HttpClientErrorException or HttpServerErrorException**). What would be the flow in this case? **Would the catch part in mainCall() in method C execute**? I have almost 5 chain call in my code but tried to simplify here and generated this sceario.

Comment: This isn't a complete example, but exceptions will continue to bubble up until they're caught or the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the statement `value = callService();` in the method `callMethodTwo` throws

1. an exception of type `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException` or their subtypes, it will be caught by the following `catch` block. This `catch` block will throw a new exception of type `MyException` which will be bubble up to `methodOne` which in turn bubble it up to `mainCall` where it will be finally caught by the `catch` block.
2. an exception of type `MyException` or its subtypes, it will be bubbled up from `callMethodTwo` to `callMethodOne` to `mainCall` where it will be finally caught by the `catch` block.
3. an exception of any other type, it will be bubbled up from `callMethodTwo` to `callMethodOne` to `mainCall` to the calling method of `mainCall`.

Answer (score 0):

Exception other than handled exception wont be going into that catch block, so myException will not be thrown by callMethodTwo.

Answer (score 0):

Execute and validate it. You'll never forget. callMethodTwo() will throw uncaught exception. A.methodOne() will throw the same back to. C.catch will catch it.

Comment: So what would be the behavior in C? I am catching only myException and doing something there. If it is the uncaught exception, what will happen in my catch in C? Will the flow go inside it?

Comment: The other exception you're not catching in C becomes uncaught exception. See the first two paragraphs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Answer (score 0):

you have not called any method of A/B in C mainCall(). You should have some code which could throw MyException then only you can catch there.